# How to optimize this sql query with xml column

Tags: sql, hash, query-optimization

I have a query with left join with result containing xml column.Need to optimize this.

This query contain xml column and when running it take more than 10 mins.

```
 SELECT *
into #temp from
( SELECT *
FROM table_a as a
left join table_b as b on a.a1_ID=b.b1
left join table_c as c on a.a2=c.c1
left join table_d as d on a.a3=d.d1  
left join table_e as e on a.a4=e.e1
where  (work_status = 5) OR (Status_CD in (0,1)))
```

Comment: Show us table and index definitions, and an explain/execution plan output.

Comment: BTW, which dbms are you using?

Comment: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_a] ADD  CONSTRAINT [table_a] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [table_a_1] ASC,
 [table_a_2] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO